# How to kill process with watchdog?

Tags: c, linux, process, watchdog

I need kill an C program if it doesn't respond.
I manage the watchdog within this program but I can only restart the system. I want to manage the watchdog to restart the program, the same C program where I manage the watchdog.

It is possible to do?

I've this code:

```
int interval;      /* Watchdog timeout interval (in secs) */
int bootstatus;      /* Wathdog last boot status */
char *dev;      /* Watchdog default device file */

int next_option;   /* getopt iteration var */
char kick_watchdog;   /* kick_watchdog options */

/* Init variables */
dev = WATCHDOGDEV;
interval = 10;
kick_watchdog = 0;
```

and inside the main loop I have:

```
ioctl(fd, WDIOC_KEEPALIVE, NULL);
```

if I need stop it:

```
write(fd, "V", 1);
/* Closing the watchdog device will deactivate the watchdog. */
close(fd);
```

Comment: Watchdog systems are hardware and force a hard restart if triggered, resetting all the internal hardware and executing from the reset address.  Configure your system to run your app at start-up.

Comment: The chances are you need a separate program to manage the watching, because if the other isn’t responding, it’s watchdog thread may be stuck too.

Comment: We need clarity on what your goals are, @crossmax.  Watchdogs need to be incorporated into the overall design of a system.  It sounds like you want to relax your current design in some way; that might be fine or it might defeat the purpose of having the watchdog.  Supervisory processes, e.g., systemd, have facilities for implementing software watchdogs to automatically restart a service.  You would probably keep the HW watchdog in your critical service, and add a software watchdog with a shorter timeout so that restarting the service may prevent total system restart.

Comment: Ok, I'll run my process from systemd and read more about its specific configuration. I asked why I thought I could invoke the watchdog to kill my process, not to reset the entire system